# how to get the full token balance of an address BSCSCAN API

Tags: cryptography, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain, bscscan

I'm working on BSCSCAN API. My goal is to get full balance for a given address as you can see on this page:

```
https://bscscan.com/tokenholdings?a=0x1c82bdb6a93f50a564155ddbcb9cf1b1a244d169
```

I checked the documentation on BscScan Website, and it seems I just could get:

-BNB BALANCE (not the full token balance) for a given address

-BALANCE of an address by giving the contract address of a single token
While I want to get the full balance for a given address. What is the right endpoints I should use? Thank you in advice.

Comment: Only found https://bscscan.com/tokencheck-tool

Comment: Need to clarify what you need? I can get the balance of an appropriate token based on my wallet address. If so, we done with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This API returns the token Balance of and address

```
https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=YOURCONTRACTADDRESS&address=YOURADDRESS&tag=latest&apikey=YOURAPIKEY
```

Answer (score 0):

This API returns the Value of BNB and not the Value of Tokens in BNB

```
https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x0Bb3A1517624Ff45186Df879E9292f67750F8EB0&apikey=YOURAPIKEYBSCSCAN
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is an API route where you just specify the walletAddress, and not the contract address: (It requires a paid bscScan plan.)
https://docs.bscscan.com/api-endpoints/tokens#get-address-bep20-token-holding